# iOS Streaming MP3 File

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, buffer, mp3

I am a relatively new developer to iOS and I am writing an application that deals with streaming audio from an mp3 file on a website.

I want to play the audio as I stream it and I want the user to be able to scrub through the audio.

I have seen other posts use

```
NSData *songData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];    
[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songData error:nil];
```

But dataWithContentsOfURL: is synchronous and will block the main thread and is not streaming, and not what I am looking for.

Ideally I am looking for some way that I can access the bytes of data as I receive them, store them in a buffer, and then play that possibly incomplete buffer at some point (not necessarily immediately) while I get the rest of the data

I am not sure If there is a way to do this with AVPlayer, or if I need to look into Core Audio etc.

Can someone please send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example provided by Apple how to receive stream and parse it.

[Apple example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AudioFileStreamExample/Introduction/Intro.html)

[audioFileStreamParser Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/index.html)

Comment: [link](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) Here is a guide how to fix some problems which may occur using Apples code and how to seek through audio.

Answer (score 0):

`AVPlayer` supports steaming.  `AVAudioPlayer` does not.

Something like this snippet, assuming that you have already created a property called `songPlayer`:

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
self.songPlayer = player;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.songPlayer currentItem]];
[self.songPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    //  code here when song reached the end

}
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == self.songPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if (self.songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");

        } else if (self.songPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
            [self.songPlayer play];


        } else if (self.songPlayer.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have been using AVPlayer but by looking at the network activity while running my app, it looks like it downloads all of the song immediately  instead of streaming.